# Javascript function inside jQuery template is not working correctly

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-templates

I'm trying to build a list of checkboxes by using jQuery.tmpl
It'll list an array of items with a checkbox near them, and I want to check some of these checkboxes parametrically...

The template code is:

```
<ul>
{{each(i,val) Values}}
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" {{if $.inArray(i, Default) != -1}} checked="checked"{{/if}}>
        <em>${val}</em>
    </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

and the template definition:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tpl_selector').tmpl({
            Default: [1,2],
            Values: {
                1: 'Item 1',
                2: 'Item 2',
                3: 'Item 3'
            }
        }).appendTo('#area');

    });
</script>
```

So the Item 1 and Item 2 should be checked in this case. The list is created with no problem, but `{{if $.inArray(i, Default) != -1}} checked="checked"{{/if}}` part is not working.

However, when I replace 'i' with a number, it works: 
`{{if $.inArray(1, Default) != -1}} checked="checked"{{/if}}`

I doesn't make any sense at all... Do you have any suggestions?

Another logic to fill the checkboxes is ok too, like I don't know smt. like a callback function after the rendering completes or else...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The problem

In JavaScript objects, the key **is always a string**. Your `Default` array contains *numbers*, but the "needle" you're passing in (`i`) is a *string*, so `$.inArray` will always return `false`,.

[**jsfiddle 0**](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/WqM6B/)

#### The solutions

Any one of these will work:

1. Make `Values` a proper array, rather than an object "indexed" by strings containing numbers.

   - [**jsfiddle 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/WqM6B/1/) (Note the zero-based indexing!)
2. Make `Defaults` an array of strings.

   - [**jsfiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/WqM6B/2/)
3. `parseInt()` the `Values` key (`i`) when you pass it to `$.inArray()`. I think this is an ugly fix.

   - [**jsfiddle 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/WqM6B/3/)

---

Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thank you so much for the well explained answer... :) #2 is what I need as the keys matter...